# Terraform - local-exec - curl command - The filename or extension is too long

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Im provisioning an Azure Search resource in terraform.

as part of the provisioning process im trying to add the index, indexer and data source using the REST API using curl

```
# PUT request to create Cognitive Search index
resource "null_resource" "search_index" {
  triggers = {
    configuration = sha256(local.index_config)
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOF
      curl --location --request PUT "https://${azurerm_search_service.instance.name}.search.windows.net/indexes/${local.index_name}?api-version=${local.api_version}" \
        --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
        --header "api-key: ${azurerm_search_service.instance.primary_key}" \
        --data-raw "${local.index_config}"
    EOF
  }
    depends_on = [
    azurerm_search_service.instance
  ] 
}
```

however when running **terraform apply** I get the following error.

```
│ Error: local-exec provisioner error
│
│   with module.azure_search.null_resource.search_index,
│   on modules\azure_search\main.tf line 13, in resource "null_resource" "search_index":
│   13:   provisioner "local-exec" {
│
│ Error running command '      curl --location --request PUT
│ "https://searchdev.search.windows.net/indexes/searchdev?api-version=2021-04-30-Preview" \
│         --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
│         --header "api-key: ####the key####" \
 }"     \"@odata.etag\": \"\\"0xxxxxxxx1\\"\"Search.BM25Similarity\",kenizerV2\": [],null,",",er\",
│ ': fork/exec C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe: The filename or extension is too long.. Output:
```

can anyone point me in the right direction to what the issue is?

Comment: Does this curl work when you run it manually, outside of TF?